# Modernizr Generated content (Smily Face)

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

Why is modernizer genrating a smily face ...

[image]

Its from the generated content div. I cant seem to replicate the effect on a fresh empty HTML file

**UPDATE**

I think the smily face comes from

[image]

```
@font-face {font-family:"font";src:url("//:")}@media (touch-enabled),(-webkit-touch-enabled),(-moz-touch-enabled),(-o-touch-enabled),(-ms-touch-enabled),(-khtml-touch-enabled),(modernizr){#touch{top:9px;position:absolute}}@media (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d),(-moz-transform-3d),(-o-transform-3d),(-ms-transform-3d),(-khtml-transform-3d),(modernizr){#csstransforms3d{left:9px;position:absolute}}#generatedcontent:after{content:":)"}
```

Comment: I don't... see any smiley faces in that picture you're posting?

Comment: @Yi Jiang, see my updated post

Comment: Please post actual code instead of an image of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a bug. You should file stuff like that our bug tracker, bro!

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues

but anyway we are fixing. :)

btw did you notice this on iPad or something? typically shit like this only happens on slow machines... though that looks like firebug.. what FF and OS version plz?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing, and in my case it's happening on an iPad. It only appears for a second while the page is downloading, but it did make me think something devious was going on at first! Took me a little while to realise it was Modernizr as it doesn't happen in my desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/.

While I did not see a smiley in your picture I do not doubt that may be the case, it is part of an example of a compatible CSS @font-face declaration per Paul Irish's recommendation.

> There has been concern over specifying
>   local font names. The primary reason
>   is that you cede control to the user's
>   machine, potentially showing a locally
>   installed font instead of the one you
>   want to serve. While that will load
>   faster, there's a very small chance
>   the file could be wrong.
>
> To account for this gotcha, I've
>   specified a local font name of '☺'.
>   Yes, it's a smiley face. The OpenType
>   spec indicates any two-byte unicode
>   characters won't work in a font name
>   on Mac at all, so that lessens the
>   likelihood that someone actually
>   released a font with such a name. This
>   technique is recommended if you think
>   a locally installed version of this
>   font is not in your best interest.

Comment: I doubt your browser is interpreting the unicode character as an ascii smiley face. Perhaps it is just a joke on Modernizer's part. It looks like that might be a test to see if the browser supports CSS generated content, so they test the width after adding a smiley face.